# Windows 7 set proxy only for some domain

Tags: windows, proxy

I'm behind a firewall without access to internet and I have a server proxy (squid) that I can set in every software when I want access to internet.

There is some way for set the proxy at system level, only for some domain?

eg. I want to open only "superuser.com" domain at system level for every software (Firefox, Chrome, IE, `batch` - `curl`, etc) without configure each single software?